# Python split a list into smaller lists depending on original list length

Tags: python, arrays, list, split, dataset

I am trying to come up with a function to split the length of a list evenly depending on it's original length.

So for example if I have a dataset returned that is 2000 I would like to split it into 4. Whereas if the dataset is 1500 split it into 3.

Then to call the function:

```
Thread_A_DATA, Thread_B_DATA = split_list( SQL_RETURN )
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
if len(dataset) <= 1000:
    # Split in 2
    a, b = split_list(dataset, 2)
if len(dataset) > 1000 or len(dataset) <= 1500:
    # Split in 3
    a, b, c = split_list(dataset, 3)

# etc etc...
```

I've managed to split a dataset in half using this code found previously on stackoverflow:

```
def split_list( a_list ):
    half = len( a_list ) / 2
    return a_list[:half], a_list[half:]
```

But I can't work it out with 3,4 or 5 splits!

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you don't want to split every 500 elements but instead split in 2 if there are less than 1000 elements, in 3 if less than 1500, 4 for 2000, etc. But if there are 1700 elements, you would split in 4 groups of 425 elements (that's what I understand by "split evenly").

So, here's my solution:

```
def split_list(a_list, number_of_splits):
    step = len(a_list) / number_of_splits + (1 if len(a_list) % number_of_splits else 0)
    return [a_list[i*step:(i+1)*step] for i in range(number_of_splits)]

l = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5]
print l
print split_list(l, 3)
print split_list(l, 2)
```

#### Output

```
[1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5]
[[1, 8, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 1, 5], [3, 1, 2, 5]]
[[1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5]]
```

edit: Python 3 version:

```
def split_list(a_list, number_of_splits):
    step = len(a_list) // number_of_splits + (1 if len(a_list) % number_of_splits else 0)
    return [a_list[i*step:(i+1)*step] for i in range(number_of_splits)]

l = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5]
print(l)
print(split_list(l, 3))
print(split_list(l, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3

```
def splitList(L):
  return[L[i:i+500] for i in range(0, len(L), 500)]
```

Python 2

```
def splitList(L):
  return[L[i:i+500] for i in xrange(0, len(L), 500)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_it(a_list,size_of_split):
    return zip(*[iter(a_list)]*size_of_split)
```

is fun

```
print split_it(range(100),3)  # splits it into groups of 3
```

unfortunatly this will truncate the end of the list if it does not divide evenly into split_size ... you can fix it like so

```
return zip(*[iter(a_list)]*size_of_split) + [tuple(a_list[-(len(a_list)%size_of_split):])]
```

if you wanted to cut it into 7 pieces say you can find the size of the split by

```
split_size = len(a_list) / num_splits
```

Comment: It looks like you don't add the last 2 items as expected:
>>> l = [1, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 5]
>>> split_it(l, 3)
[(1, 8, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 1), (5, 3, 1), 2, 5]

Comment: `[(1, 8, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 1), (5, 3, 1), [2, 5]]` that's better but still weird to mix tuples and lists :).

Comment: But now, I have `[(1, 8, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 1), (5, 3, 1), 2, 5]` again. It works with `return zip(*[iter(a_list)]*size_of_split) + [tuple(a_list[-(len(a_list)%size_of_split):])]` however.

Comment: bah correct again ... I wanted to avoid that(explicit tuple cast) but meh whatever :P

Comment: I actually spent some time to understand what was going on there :). I like your solution, that's a shame it's getting so complex for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7

```
>>> import math
>>> lst = range(35)
>>> t = 3 # how many items to be splited
>>> n = int(math.ceil(len(lst) / float(t)))
>>> res = [lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]
>>> res
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]]
```